# My form does not store the params in model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails project in which I have to save subscribers data in the database without refreshing the page!

So I coded an Ajax button. when I click the button an alert popups and returns the ID of new user that has just been created. The problem is when I look at rails console for last record of model *User.last* all fields of the record is nil (except ID). How can I fix this problem?

---

routes:

```
users_new GET  /users/new(.:format)    users#new
    users GET  /users/index(.:format)  users#index
   create POST /users/create(.:format) users#create
```

here is my view in app/views/users/new.html.haml

```
.form1
  %h1 
    Subscriber
  =form_for @user do |form|
    - unless @user.errors.empty?
      - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        .alert.alert-danger
          %ul
            - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
              %li= message
    %div{ :data => { :role => :content} }
      .row.form-group
        .col-lg-3
          %label 
            Email:
          =form.text_field :email, :class => 'form-control'
      .row.form-group
        .col-lg-3
          %label 
            Name:
          =form.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control'
      .row.form-group
        .col-lg-3
          %label 
            Phone Number:
          =form.text_field :phone_number, :class => 'form-control'
      .row.form-group
        .col-lg-3
          %label    
            Address:
          =form.text_field :address, :class => 'form-control'
      %ui-grid-a
        %ui-block-a
          %a.primary{ :data => { :role => :button, :remote => create_path, :parent => '.form1', :success => 'saved' } } Save
```

This is the controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new params[:user]
    @user.save
    render :json => @user  
  end

end
```

My js file :

```
function saved(user){
  alert(user.id);
}
```

Comment: Your JS file is `.js.erb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things which could cause this problem

Considering you're a rails newbie (*welcome!*), I thought it best to outline the issues in an answer, rather than in the comments

---

**Routes.rb**

There's a function in the rails routes called [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) - this allows you to create a number of rails routes through a single function call - *`resources :controller`*

You seem to be manually declaring your routes, which is generally considered bad practice for generic functions like `new` or `create` I'd advise you to first change your routes.rb file to this:

```
#app/config/routes.rb
resources :users
```

This will give you a set of pre-generated routes, which will you keep your code efficient

---

**Users_Controller.rb**

```
 #/app/controllers/users_controller.rb
 def create
    @user = User.new params[:user]
    @user.save
    render :json => @user  
  end
```

You have a big problem here

You're using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) (which is Javascript), and are not handling the request properly. You really need to use [`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) to handle the header-type of the request, and to ensure you're able to engage with the app properly

Try this:

```
 #/app/controllers/users_controller.rb
 def create
    @user = User.new params[:user]
    @user.save

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
        format.json {  render :json => @user   }
        format.html
    end 
 end
```

Something you need to ensure is you know the differences between JSON & a standard "Javascript" call through Ajax. [`JSON`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is basically a way to deal with small arrays (called JSON Objects), which can be passed through ajax; whilst a full javascript call has much more scope

---

**Create.js.erb**

`.js.erb` is basically the same as `.html.erb`

In your `create.js.erb`, you rely on a json object to return your new user's ID. Although this might be considered O.K, I think you can make it more efficient by cutting out the json object completely

In `create.js.erb`, you don't need any functions to fire things. It just works like an HTML View, and so you should just put the code in you want fired:

```
#/app/views/users/create.js.erb  
alert(<%=j @user.id %>);
```

Although the methodology here is correct, I don't know if it will output anything because we're not explicitly passing the `@user` variable

Comment: No problem buddy. I just noticed, though, that you will need to include [`strong_params`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) when you use the `create` functions. If you need help with this, I can edit my answer

Comment: I got it, no need! ;)